The event.waitUntil not working for vscode extension
this is a extension code. the purpose is i want to prevent the document to save after 10s. but it not working. why?
 vscode.workspace.onWillSaveTextDocument(async (event) => {
      console.log('start')
      event.waitUntil(new Promise((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          console.log('end')
          resolve()
        }, 10_000);
      }))
    });


Does the setTimeout() take "10_000" or just "10000"?
